# Ultraportable full keyboard or keyboard add-ons?

Tags: mac, laptop, keyboard, macbook

I love my MacBook Pro.  I *hate* my MacBook Pro's keyboard.  It doesn't have an actual delete key (the key marked "delete" is actually backspace - deletes the character before the cursor, not after).  It doesn't have page up / page down.  I don't understand why anyone would release a laptop keyboard without these things.  I can live without it but a numpad would be nice, too.

Sadly, I'm not going to shove a regular keyboard into my backpack to tote around (it's barely long enough for the 17" laptop!).

So... can anyone point me to either (1) an ultraportable keyboard that can easily be hooked up to a Mac [i.e., firewire or USB, standard drivers], or (2) an auxiliary insert/delete/home/end/pageup/pagedown block that meets the same criteria?  I'm thinking something like [this](http://www.gadgets-weblog.com/50226711/ultra_portable_keyboard_with_a_darth_vader_feel_to_it.php) or [this](http://cgi.ebay.com/ws/eBayISAPI.dll?ViewItem&item=380066112496&rvr_id=&crlp=1_263602_263622&UA=WXF%3F&GUID=62267e6b1260a0aad244bcf4ff6b8213&itemid=380066112496&ff4=263602_263622), only with all the keys.  (And ideally not $200, but I'm getting that desperate...)

Comment: Fn-Delete will perform a "forward delete", just as an FYI.  I assume you're already aware that Fn-UpArrow / Fn-DownArrow perform PageUp/PageDown, as it's labeled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laser keyboard is a no no! They are fun for the first word or to use on a train... but after a while, you will just be so annoyed by it! They are a brilliant gadget but they are just rubbish in actual use.

I was going to say a Foldup keyboard, they have the tactile feedback (although not as good as a keyboard) and are "alright".

The other solution I would actually (highly) recommend is a mini / small form factor keyboard [such as the one here](http://cgi.ebay.com/ULTRA-SLIM-USB-MINI-KEYBOARD-COMPUTER-PC-LAPTOP-MAC-NEW_W0QQitemZ140377027787QQcmdZViewItemQQptZUK_Computing_ComputerComponents_KeyboardsMice?hash=item20af1f74cb). It has what you want, although it is a little cramped.

[image]

Comment: Hmm, that looks like it could be made to work.

You mention the foldups - do you know of one that works with Mac OS X?

Comment: Keyboards should just be keyboards, other than the command button, you should have no problem using the foldup you linked to or the mini one I showed.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using a full-size roll-up keyboard (not the mini version).

[image]

It's just great for traveling, stashes away neatly and is spill proof (little accidents can happen), costs around 30 Euro.

I also have a laser keyboard. Yes, the coolness factor is not to be underestimated but they certainly are not ideal for a bumpy ride!